# Convert a Time list to ISO Format Python

Tags: python

I'm writing a `NETCDF` File of Temperature. My time range is 6 hourly data for 1 year(so `1460` data points, or `0:1459`). I want to convert these values to ISO Format `YYYYMMDDHHMM`. For example, I want the 1st time to read `200801010000`, the 2nd time to read `200801010600` and so on. How can I code Python to accomplish this?

Comment: use datetime module, specifically [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) and [`isoformat`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat)

Comment: `datetime.isoformat()` adds in hyphens and colons, to match ISO 8601. The specified format is similar but not exactly the same as true 'ISO format'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will generate all dates and times in the format that you want:

```
import datetime

d = datetime.datetime(2008, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2009, 1, 1)

while d <= end:
    print(d.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S"))
    d += datetime.timedelta(hours=6)
```

Comment: Well someone didn't like that answer ;)